# Webpack and angular2 not builiding background-image from css

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webpack

I've set a project using Angular2 -> Webpack documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#top

The problem is that the images from .css files are not build, in the browser I get 404 because they are not present/built in the /dist/assets folder.

I don't want to use absolute paths and place them manually in dist/assets/.. .I already have them in /public/images/..

I want to use relative paths and hashes that webpack automatically creates, and let webpack load them in /dist/assets/..

the .css file looks like this:

```
  background: url('../../../public/images/randomImage.png') center no-repeat;
```

webpack.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'css-to-string-loader!css-loader'
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.css$/,
            //     include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            //     loader: 'raw-loader'
            // },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-with-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --compress",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

my current solution to solve this was to switch from raw-loader to css-to-string-loader

here's is the code again:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: 'css-to-string-loader!css-loader'
},
// {
//     test: /\.css$/,
//     include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
//     loader: 'raw-loader'
// },
```

Is it okey ? are there any other solutions ?

Comment: Try this `background: url('/dist/assets/randomImage.png') center no-repeat;`

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Your solution is incomplete. What if the image has a `hash` suffix? What if the image has a small size and it should be converted and used as `base64` url and bundle it into `js`. `React` and `webpack` + `es6` works fine. But `angular2` + `ts` + `webpack`, I am still looking for a completed solution. I saw the question is asked 8 months ago and there is no anwser here. Maybe I should be cautious about using `angular2` + `ts` + `webpack` techs stack.